# If isNaN not throwing non Double inputs

Tags: java

I don't know if im using the isNaN right but can you guys help me on using it to accept only numbers in inputs

```
while (true){
    System.out.println("first number");
    num1=input.nextDouble();
    if (num1.isNaN()){
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
    else;
        break;
}
```

My issue is that when i input a letter, it is not displaying the invalid input message. It just stops the program because i input a letter which is not the error i want to see

Comment: Tell us which input you have tried and the result, and why it differs from your expectations.

Comment: What do you mean? My issue is that when i input a letter, it is not displaying the invalid input message. It just stops the program because i input a letter which is not the error i want to see

Comment: @ShampauTolentino Why do you think `num1.isNan()` is executed at all? `input.nextDouble()` throws an exception if the input is not parsable as a double. If you want to handle it, then `catch` the exception. [More info here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Answer (score 3):

Scanner does not return a NaN when an invalid input is given. Instead it throws an `InputMismatchException`. You could use a try-catch statement to catch this exception and handle it appropriately.

Alternatively, Scanner also has a `hasNextDouble()` function. This waits and checks if the next value is valid as a double, without actually consuming it.

So you could write your loop like this:

```
while (true){
    System.out.println("Please input a number:");
    if (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid number.");
        break;
    }
    double number = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Your input: " + number);
}
```

[See the documentation on Scanner.hasNextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--)

Comment: Note: it's because NaN is not an error message, but a value that a double can hold. the isNaN() checks if the value of a double is NaN, not that it is a valid value. But yeah, it stops one line earlier, because a string is not a double.

Comment: @RobCo, i tried the try catch and put a double input (num1) inside the try, the result was, num1 became missing as the system says that it is not initialized.